# D3 Linear Scaling - Color code mismatch

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linear-programming

I'm using 3 different scaling Quantile, Quantize and Linear from D3 Library with Color's as ranges.  Quantile and Quantize seems to be working fine where in **linear scale doesn't seems to work.**

Here is the sample code.

```
var measures = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var colorScale = ["#f7fcfd", "#ccece6", "#66c2a4", "#238b45", "#00441b"];
var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain(measures).range(colorScale);

document.write('Linear ');
document.write(scale(1) + ',' + scale(2) + ',' + scale(3) + ',' + scale(6) + ',' + scale(7) + ',' + scale(8) + ',' + scale(9)+' ');

scale = d3.scale.quantize().domain(measures).range(colorScale);
document.write('Quantize ');
document.write(scale(1) + ',' + scale(2) + ',' + scale(3) + ',' + scale(4) + ',' + scale(5) + ',' + scale(6) + ',' + scale(7)+' ');
```

Link to [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vigneshncc/0ge750bL/2/)

You can clearly see the values for 9,8,7,6 are #000 in case of Linear scaling.  But in Quantize it's working fine.

Kindly help me where I am going wrong in this case.
Hope my question is clear.  Thanks in anticipation for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the range for linear is the length of the colorScale, thus, this behavior is correct. See https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Quantitative-Scales.md#linear 
`Given a value x in the input domain, returns the corresponding value in the output range.`
. A usual solution to this is to try something like `scale(5 % colorScale.length)`

Hope this helps!